# How can I model multiple numerical variables using a mixture of numerical and non-numerical predictors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, linear-regression, multivariate-testing

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| product_name | brand | price_change_percentage | release_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Toy X | X | 20 | 2001 |
| Toy Y | Y | -12 | 2020 |

I would like to use Tensorflow to predict price_change_percentage based on product_name, brand, and release_year.

Which kind of Tensorflow model should I conduct and how can I change the non-numerical product_name and brand values into numerical values? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try tensorflow_decision_forests

Comment: Thank you! Can I pls ask why?

Comment: @mdaoust, thank you for your suggestion. But I still need to change non-numerical values to numerical values to work with tensorflow_decision_forests... Can you help me suggest the best way to do this? Should I got with One-hot encoding or Word Embedding? Thank you!!

Comment: "But I still need to change non-numerical values to numerical values". No, you don't. Decision forests handle this automatically. Try the google sheets extension:
https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests/simple_ml_for_sheets

Comment: you will need a RNN/Transformer to convert the name in a fixed size vector, same as for brand (but it's arguable that the name can help your model to predice the price change), and then the usual FFNN.... but for tabular data, probably RF or gradient boosting techniques work better